# affect all images those width a minimum width

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension. I have a doubt. I want that every images of any site has a style css with minimal width.

I need not affect all images, only those with a minimum width.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/ceu6ho1s/

Comment: What Have you tried from now ? What is not working ? What is the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all element have `min-width="0px"` so simply check if images not have `min-width-"0px"` do this

**for example**

```js
$("img").each(function(e) {
  if ($(this).css("min-width") != "0px") {
    $(this).addClass("foo")
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("foo") //no need this line but just added as a fallback 
  }
});
```

```css
.test {
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" style="min-width:100%">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="test">
```

in this condition i have added foo class on those images who have min-width css you can do what ever you want.

i don't know its a proper solution or not but it will help you do what ever you want.

thanks